# vuetify free template theme-blog block-level elements

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I build with vue-cli webpack and use npm.

I just took this template and used it as it is.

However, the execution screen is broken and the images are not visible.

I have confirmed that images have been loaded from Chrome.

"[Vuetify] v-ripple can only be used on block-level elements".

What can I try?

[this is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0goi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";

copy this link in you app.js file before importing vuetify.